# Combine CSS Attribute and Pseudo-Element Selectors?

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-selectors, pseudo-element

How can I combine a pseudo-element selector (`:after`) with an attribute selector (`[title]`)?

I tried using `div[title]:after`, but this doesn't work in Chrome.

HTML:

```
<div title="foo">This div has a title.</div>
<div>This div does not have a title.</div>
```

CSS:

```
div:after {
    content: "NO";
}
div[title]:after {
    content: "YES";
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jmAX6/

It shows me "YES" at the end of each of those div's, when it should show "NO" after the second div.

I'm running Chrome 17.0.963.38. It seems to work fine in Safari 5.1.2.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This looks like a bug, which has finally been [reported](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=125719). If you add a CSS rule for `div[title]` *anywhere* in your stylesheet with at least one declaration, your `div[title]:after` rule will magically apply. For example:

```
div:after {
    content: "NO";
}
div[title] {
    display: block;
}
div[title]:after {
    content: "YES";
}
```

See [the updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/jmAX6/8).

It also seems to have something to do with your second `div` having or not having certain HTML attributes, as shown in the comments below.

Comment: Yeah looks like a bug, check this one out: http://jsfiddle.net/jmAX6/6/ Adding a class to the div with no title magically makes it work.

Comment: @Madmartigan: I'm finding a few other related bugs too. Now filing a report just seems like a chore. I'll do it later if I remember to.

Comment: Looks like it's also dependent on the attribute used, so this definitely has to be a bug: http://jsfiddle.net/jmAX6/7/ Also check out the one with `tabindex`, when you tab into it, the pseudo element corrects itself.

Comment: @Madmartigan: Made me smirk :)