# :before with an attribute selector

Tags: css, forms, css-selectors

I have the following html form

```
<div>
    <p>Field1</p>
    <input type="text" name="fld_one" id="fld_one" value="" />
</div>
<div>
    <p>Field2</p>
    <input type="text" name="fld_two" id="fld_two" required value="" />
</div>
```

I want to use CSS to mark required fields like so

```
div input[required]:before { color: #f00; content: "*"; }
```

However this css line does not make a visible change in the document.

For reference I was able to modify all required fields with the following:

```
div input[required] { background-color: #000; }
```

TL;DR - Can the :before pseudo-class be used with an attribute selector?  If so, how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`:before` is a pseudo-element, not a pseudo-class. It can be used with an attribute selector, but you can't use it with `input` elements with some browsers because it is a replaced element. (Some browsers, because it's [not very well-defined](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#before-after-content) whether they're supposed to work, although most lean toward "no".)

The reason why your attribute selector works is because you're applying styles to the `input` element itself, which works consistently in every browser.

Comment: By the way, [some browsers have trouble with pseudo-elements and attribute selectors regardless of actual element being selected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8951822/combine-css-attribute-and-pseudo-element-selectors/8988418#8988418). I have no idea if this has been fixed yet.

Answer (score 5):

Pseudo elements [do not work with `input` elements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4574946/871050), as they have no content.

From the [specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#before-after-content):

> Authors specify the style and location of generated content with the
>   :before and :after pseudo-elements. As their names indicate, the
>   :before and :after pseudo-elements specify the location of content
>   before and after an *element's document tree content*. The 'content'
>   property, in conjunction with these pseudo-elements, specifies what is
>   inserted.

Input elements have no childNodes in the DOM, hence, no content property to insert into.

---

As a possible workaround, apply the stars to the **labels** instead of the input elements

Answer (score 3):

`:before` is not valid on `<input>` as it doesn't have "content" - see: [CSS content generation before or after 'input' elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4574912/css-content-generation-before-input-elements) for a full explanation.

The "traditional" way of doing it is inserting the * on `p` or `label` (label is more semantic).