# Styles applied to multiple selectors won't work for both

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have this two rules in scss:

```
    .fakeinput, input[type=text]{
                    background: white;
                    padding: 10px 0px;
                    border: 1px solid #211915;
                    display: inline-block;
                    width: 100%;
                    height: 35px;
                    &:before{
                        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 white;
                        border-bottom: 1px solid black;
                        border-left: 1px solid black;
                        content: " ";
                        display: block;
                        height: 10px;
                        left: -6px;
                        position: relative;
                        top: 0px;
                        @include transform(rotate(45deg));
                        width: 10px;
                    }
                }

Wich would generate this css:

/* line 60, ../sass/_search.scss */
section#search > div > form .fakeinput, section#search > div > form input[type=text] {
  background: white;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  border: 1px solid #211915;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
}
/* line 67, ../sass/_search.scss */
section#search > div > form .fakeinput:before, section#search > div > form input[type=text]:before {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  height: 10px;
  left: -6px;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  width: 10px;
}
```

It works fine for the .fakeinput but not for the input[type=text]

You can check the result here:

http://jsfiddle.net/QAAYd/2/

(the pseudo arrow is only shown for the fakeinput elements)

what am i missing here?

Comment: `:before` adds content to be rendered as if it was actually a _child element_ of the targeted element – but input elements can not have child elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not **working Because**

`:before` is a **pseudo-element**, `not a pseudo-class.`

So please don't used to this on `input tag`

More info **[Go to here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12411761/before-with-an-attribute-selector)**

Comment: I see! thanks! so my only chance is to add another html element, right?

Comment: now you can used to label or div as like this <lable><div class=""><input type="text" /></div></label> now define your div display inline-block and apply css to in your inner div